# How much correction can a stargate perform?

Tags: stargate

In the first episode of Star gate it is revealed the reason they have always failed at gate dialling is that due to the shift of planets/galaxies/universe expansion and the fact they don't have a DHD to correct for this.

Two questions then spring to mind:

How much correction can a DHD perform?

How closely does a non-DHD gate's destination need to be unchanged for it to successfully dial?

Answer (score 2):

It is revealed in a few episodes that they the dialing computer performs the job of a DHD, compensating for various types of movement of the objective gate(s).

The SG wiki has some relevant information regarding the developement of the dialing computer
http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Dialing_computer

At the moment I cannot find any information regarding the degree of drift a target would have to undergo to be impossible to dial, but presumably the DHDs would constantly update their database of objective coordinates, regularly compensating for small amounts of drift.

This article goes on to briefly explain the DHD update procedure http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Correlative_update_system

Comment: Good link but it doesn't really say how much correction it can perform.

Comment: I know, trying to find the  information for you, but as always with pseudoscience it's hard to pin down nice juicy numbers to bash around :(

Comment: We do know that within around 6 AU stargates begin interfering with each other.  Once entering the Tau'ri solar system Klorel's stargate is able to lock out the earth stargate, and I believe it is shown with Jupiter in the background.